# How to move objects to the z and y coordinates of the mouse in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[I'm trying to make the orange box follow my mouse. But with my current script, it only goes about a quarter of a unit towards the direction of my mouse, then stops. I am completely stuck & lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUNbM.png)

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine;


public class drag : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, worldPos.y, worldPos.z);
    }
}
```

Any help? This is for a game jam, I've got around 48 more hours to finish. Thanks!

Comment: What precisely is `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, worldPos.y, worldPos.z);` trying to do?

Comment: Try `Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, transform.position.z));` rather than the nearClipPlane of the camera.

Comment: @HumanWrites It doesn't work. When I move my mouse out of a small portion of the screen in the center, the worldPos goes CRAZY ( 1 trillion+ on the x coordinate etc ) and it doesn't go to my mouse in the first place, it goes to like the opposite side.

https://imgur.com/a/3fRX1jT

Comment: @Putnam it's moving the orange box ( The script is attached to it ) to the y and z position of the worldPos variable ( what is supposed to be the mouse position ) and it keeps the x coordinate of it the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Get the mouse position
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

    // Set the z component of the mouse position to the absolute distance between the camera's z and the object's z.
    mousePos.z = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z - transform.position.z);

    // Determine the world position of the mouse pointer
    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

    // Update the position of the object
    transform.position = worldPos;
}
```